# Safari automatically appends .txt extension to .ino files

Tags: macos

When I download an `.ino` file in OS X, my files are automatically converted to `.ino.txt` and opened by TextEdit app, even though, I have installed Arduino IDE. How can I close this feature?

Comment: Seems like a safari problem, where it renames any possibly harmful files to `.txt`.

Comment: This is not an Arduino specific question, and should be migrated to SE Ask Different.

Comment: It's not happening to me. If I download http://gammon.com.au/Arduino/Temperature_Monitor.ino it appears as a .ino file.

Comment: I don't how to migrate a question. I agree with you this is not completely an Arduino question , however I thought Arduino users may be more familiar with this issue.

Comment: Moderators migrate questions. You could provide more information, such as the place you got this .ino file from (link).

Comment: Any .ino file is downloaded as .ino.txt no matter from where I download it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this is a server issue. And one can't solve the issue by changing safari settings. The answers to the same question I found are in the below.

iMeowbot user in macrumors says that:

> "This filename modification stuff isn't something that Apple made up,
>   it comes straight out of RFC 2183 (see "2.3 The Filename Parameter"
>   and "5. Security Considerations"). While that RFC talks about
>   "messages" and "mail" it applies equally to the Web, as HTTP employs
>   MIME.
>
> OS X and Safari have no way to read the mind of the server operator,
>   and cannot tell if a mismatched media type and filename are accidental
>   or intentional. So, they follow the standard.
>
> Recent Safari versions add additional checks, such as that annoying
>   prompt for when something appears to contain an executable file. It's
>   all part of the same healthy paranoia that helps ensure that the end
>   user knows exactly what a remote server is attempting to send."

http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/safari-adding-txt-to-a-m4v-download.167086/

TETENAL user in macnn says that:

> "AFAIK the Apache server software comes with a preset of
>   extension->MIME-type assignments. If a file with an unknown extension
>   (like .dmg) is served with the MIME-type text as a fallback, Safari
>   adds a .txt extension. This behavior is arguably correct. The server
>   tells Safari it is serving a text-file, and a text file needs a .txt
>   extension on Mac to be opened with a text editor. So Safari adds one.
>   Other browsers ignore the server, which is a short term benefit for
>   the user, but in the long run a) makes the server admin not notice the
>   mistake and b) prevents the server admin to use this feature whenever
>   he intentionally wants to (as opposed to unintentionally doesn't care
>   as usually).
>
> Anyway, to fix this you can create a file .htaccess to the respective
>   folder and correctly define the missing MIME-types by adding AddType
>   application/octet-stream .dmg or AddType application/x-stuffit .sit
>   and AddType application/x-stuffit .sitx etc."

http://forums.macnn.com/82/applications/339922/safari-apending-txt-file-extensions-how/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please refrain from posting link-only answers. Links can change over time and then we'll lose the reference to the answers.  See [answer] for good info on how to correctly answer questions.  - From Review -

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I quoted the related answers.